# Formula to Adjust for Rounding Issues

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula in Excel that solves for the base number of units needed on a monthly interval with an annual growth escalator that matches in whole units the total I'm starting with.  I can't from a practical standpoint have fractions.

This is an example of the formula x is number of monthly units, y is the total number of units and the desired annual growth rate is 20%. Here is the algebra butin practice only one variable will need to be solved for `(x): y= 12x + (1.2x)*12+(1.2^2)*x*12+(1.2^3)*x*12`.  I get close using the round function but always end up a few short of the total desired due.  Is there a way to add on the difference at the end formulaically?

```
ROUND(20000/(12+(12*(1+20%))+12*(1+20%)^2+12*(1+20%)^3),0)
```

I'm extremely close but I need to make sure the total by month matches the total desired.

Comment: Can you try to visualize your example through cell input, output and desired output?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking but you can use the function SERIESSUM() to make the formula cleaner like this `=ROUND(20000/12*SERIESSUM(1.2,0,1,{1,1,1,1}),0)`

Comment: So, Do you want to know how many units you need to start (X) if every year you have a growth of 20%, for 4 years, and every year you get 12 times the "X"? So is correct to say that the numbers of years is fixed to 4? If you are working with integers only, you won't get the exact result most of times.  If x=310->y=19968. If x=311->20033

Comment: I don't know how many I need to start with but I do know that I need to reach a total and want to have a yearly growth escalator on the base quantity.  The base quantity to reach that exact total with rounding and annual escalators is what I'm looking for.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: It's really just solving for the base year's unit's I'm looking for so that with those annual escalators I can reach the 20,000 exactly.